# Clojure doseq generates huge code?

Tags: macros, clojure, code-generation

I've recently been playing with clojure and reached a problem that I'm not sure how to handle. I have a doseq with 7 parameters and it expands to a huge block, almost passing the maximum class size. Why does doseq expand to such a huge block of clojure code?

Example:

```
(def q '(doseq
[p0 (nth (:params operator) 0 (quote (nil)))
p1 (nth (:params operator) 1 (quote (nil)))
p2 (nth (:params operator) 2 (quote (nil)))
p3 (nth (:params operator) 3 (quote (nil)))
p4 (nth (:params operator) 4 (quote (nil)))
p5 (nth (:params operator) 5 (quote (nil)))
p6 (nth (:params operator) 6 (quote (nil)))]
(do-print board (:oname operator) p0 p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6)))
```

and then:

```
(macroexpand q)
```

on my machine this gives a huge chunk of code (97331 bytes). Is this normal or am I doing something wrong? Operator is a simple defrecord. Here's a link to the expanded result if anyone is interested: http://pastebin.com/6gw1q078

edit:

By doing the same, but with a **for** form I get something a few orders of magnitude smaller (3653 bytes):

```
(def q '(for
[p0 (nth (:params operator) 0 (quote (nil)))
p1 (nth (:params operator) 1 (quote (nil)))
p2 (nth (:params operator) 2 (quote (nil)))
p3 (nth (:params operator) 3 (quote (nil)))
p4 (nth (:params operator) 4 (quote (nil)))
p5 (nth (:params operator) 5 (quote (nil)))
p6 (nth (:params operator) 6 (quote (nil)))]
(do-print board (:oname operator) p0 p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6)))

(macroexpand q)
```

the result is here: http://pastebin.com/9MAKK3VD

Why is there such a huge difference between the two? The doseq form looks innocent enough, I was really surprised when I got an error saying that java class size has been exceeded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, looking at a smaller macro-expasion of `doseq` reveals the reason:

```
(loop [seq_2365 (seq [1 2])
       chunk_2366 nil
       count_2367 0
       i_2368 0]
  (if (< i_2368 count_2367)
    (let [x (.nth chunk_2366 i_2368)]
      (do x)
      (recur seq_2365 chunk_2366 count_2367 (unchecked-inc i_2368)))
    (when-let [seq_2365 (seq seq_2365)]
      (if (chunked-seq? seq_2365)
        (let [c__4197__auto__ (chunk-first seq_2365)]
          (recur (chunk-rest seq_2365) c__4197__auto__ (int (count c__4197__auto__)) (int 0)))
        (let [x (first seq_2365)]
          (do x)
          (recur (next seq_2365) nil 0 0))))))
```

Ideally we only need the last `let` form but `doseq` is emitting additional code to handle `chunked-seq` in a specific way such that it takes the first chunk and then for each item in the chunk execute the body of `doseq` and so on.

This code is generated for a single seq in `doseq` but when you have 2nd seq in it then similar code for handling chunked-seq is generated and hence it explod in size.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I was thinking it's something along those lines. It still feels like a big limitation and I'm wondering is this is intended behaviour...